# Combining 4 sets of data in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have four separate sets of data for each of the 4 quarters in the year, the columns are identical within all. What is a python function I can use to combine them into one master data set?
Thank you!

Comment: is this in pandas?

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: Yes I am using pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the pandas concat funtion for this since the dataframes are identical. See this example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"],
        "B": ["B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"],
        "C": ["C4", "C5", "C6", "C7"],
        "D": ["D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"],
    },
    index=[4, 5, 6, 7],
)


df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"],
        "B": ["B8", "B9", "B10", "B11"],
        "C": ["C8", "C9", "C10", "C11"],
        "D": ["D8", "D9", "D10", "D11"],
    },
    index=[8, 9, 10, 11],
)


frames = [df1, df2, df3]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas dataframes. It would look something like this.
Depends on how the data looks. But atleast take a look at pandas, well documented. In concat you might need to care for the index

```
import pandas as pd

set1 = pd.DataFrame(set1)
set2 = pd.DataFrame(set2)
set3 = pd.DataFrame(set3)
master_set = pd.concat(set1, set2, set3)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you for your help! Just needed to add in ignore_index also